# Align UIImage in UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying to align a UIImageView to the left of a UITableViewCell.

I thought I have to use something like

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImageView CGFloat....];
```

but as it turns out that it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to fiddle around with the image inside the UIImageView...I want to place the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell at a specific place by code.

Comment: You'll need to make a custom UITableViewCell.